# full length title tag image?

Tags: html, image, title

I've got a quick question this time, I know it might sound a bit silly, but I'd like to know if it's possible to any degree;

is it possible to have images in the `<title>` field of an html document? for example, could you have an image take up the whole of a page's title? (I'm assuming not, as many, many tacky websites would have it, but I though I aught to ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; that's totally impossible.

However, you can use unusual Unicode characters.  (and you can then hope that your users have fonts that contain those characters)

Comment: Github demonstrated this well.

Comment: @mauris: What are you referring to?

Comment: though I don't think you can change the title font, can you?

Comment: @CaptainDando: No; you can't do that in a title.  You can only use the system standard font.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't have images in titles, but I guess you could achieve something similar by playing around with favicons (You can change them with JavaScript for example).

Comment: Thanks, I'll tinker with that a bit

Comment: could you move the favicon along the title bar?

Comment: As far as I know you can't move it.